# Let textboxfor display the value it updates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got this textbox in my view inside a beginform:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Page.logoUrl)
```

When i submit, the value i put in the textbox updates the db..
I would like the textbox to display the value from the db when the
page loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use a viewmodel class for this type of thing:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public string LogoUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I use that viewmodel in the controller's action method like so.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();

    viewModel.LogoUrl = // Get this from DB.

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Finally, I can use the `LogoUrl` in the view:

```
@using IndexViewModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LogoUrl)
```

This way, you can display the `LogoUrl` when the page loads (note, you will likely have different action method named to `Index`, I was just making an assumption).